# How do I move a server to a new power source without powering it off?

Tags: migration, electrical-power, uptime

I have a server that has a single power supply that it is plugged into the wall.  I want to transfer the server over to a UPS power supply for redundancy but do now want to power off the server for the move.  The UPS is plugged into the same power source (phase) as the computer is powered on.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. There are legit tools for doing just this very thing. http://www.cru-inc.com/products/wiebetech/hotplug_field_kit_product/

Comment: @jscott Make this an answer

Comment: @jscott Because the server should probably just take the downtime hit. I'm sure it can be scheduled. If it were more critical, it would either already be on a UPS or already have dual power supplies.

Answer (score 8):

Just schedule downtime and turn the server off.

Without a dual power supply setup, you don't have any other *reasonable* options.

If there are business constraints or otherwise, you should note those in your question. Any sane organization would understand the need and justification for the power off. But I'd assume that if the server were absolutely critical, it would have dual power supplies or wouldn't be plugged into the wall in the first place.